# How to create a virtual-hosted-style presigned URL for an S3 bucket in a non US region?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, pre-signed-url

I was trying to generate a presigned URL for an S3 bucket in the `me-central-1` region using the boto3 library, as demonstrated below

```
client = boto3.client("s3", region_name="me-central-1")

return client.generate_presigned_url(
    ClientMethod="put_object",
    Params={"Bucket": bucket, "Key": path},
)
```

This generates a url with the following form: `https://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/path?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential={CREDENTIAL}/{DATE}/me-central-1/s3/aws4_request&X-Amz-Date={DATETIME}&X-Amz-Expires=1800&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature={SIGNATURE}`

However, trying to use this url results in an `IllegalLocationConstraintException` with the following message: `The me-central-1 location constraint is incompatible for the region specific endpoint this request was sent to.`

I did a bit of research into why this was happening and found that S3 endpoints going to regions other than us-east-1 needed to include the region like so: `https://bucket.s3.REGION.amazonaws.com/...`.

I then changed the boto3 client instantation to the version below:

```
client = boto3.client("s3", region_name="me-central-1", endpoint_url="https://s3.me-central-1.amazonaws.com")
```

The resulting url had the form: `https://s3.me-central-1.amazonaws.com/bucket/path?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential={CREDENTIAL}/{DATE}/me-central-1/s3/aws4_request&X-Amz-Date={DATETIME}&X-Amz-Expires=1800&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature={SIGNATURE}`

This URL seems to work without returning an `IllegalLocationConstraintException`! However, I noticed this was now a path-style request instead of a virtual-hosted-style request (as defined [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/VirtualHosting.html)). The provided webpage also states path-style requests will be discontinued, so I will not be able to use the above code for a long-term solution.

My attempts to manually change the path-style request into a virtual-hosted-style request resulted in a `SignatureDoesNotMatch` error, with the message: `The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method`.

My question would be - is there a way to make the boto3 client return a valid virtual-hosted-style presigned url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import boto3
from botocore.client import Config

client = boto3.client(
    "s3",
    region_name="me-central-1",
    endpoint_url="https://s3.me-central-1.amazonaws.com",
    config=Config(s3={'addressing_style': 'virtual'})
)

return client.generate_presigned_url(
    ClientMethod="put_object",
    Params={"Bucket": bucket, "Key": path},
)
```

Comment: Is the `endpoint_url` actually required? I always thought it's only needed for non-AWS services.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/3018

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Sounds like a bug to me

Comment: I just did some testing and you are correct! The `s3={'addressing_style': 'virtual'}` config adds the region to the endpoint without the need for an `endpoint_url`